# Avoid hardcoding in updating local database in ios

Tags: ios, sqlite

I have an iOS application that use local database feature. I don't use CoreData; I copy my sqlite file from resource bundle to Documents folder and then update / pull data from that file.
All the updates, creating table, inserting algorithm work perfectly fine in my app.

I'm just wondering for an improvement. I have more than 7 tables, and each table has different attributes. Right now I have to specify each update statement in my code, like (just an example):

```
   // for table A
   const char* sql = "update tableA Set attA1 = ?, attA2 = ? where att0 = ?";

   // .. other code here ...

   // bind it - this is the part where i am confused. 
   // each table has different attribute.. So each table will have each binding snippet?
   if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, 267, &stmt, NULL)==SQLITE_OK){
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [input1 UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 2, [input2 UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
        sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 3, input0);
    }
```

Apology if this sounds like beginner question. Is it possible to avoid "hardcoding" like this? I didn't find a way to avoid hardcoding, but I am just curious if someone has some insights.
The closest post that I found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078240/how-to-avoid-hardcoding-an-id-in-a-sql-update-trigger) - and it was fine in his case.
I have looked at many iOS sqlite db tutorial, and most of them did this since they only have 1 table in their example.

I am still learning so please don't be too harsh on me if this is an obvious/bad question. :)

Comment: You can use something like FMDB, or you can dynamically construct your own SQL statements.  It requires some planning and a fair amount of coding to produce a "framework", but it's often worth it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to remove boilerplate code by using a helper library that uses Objective C concepts instead of raw C; in the case of SQLite, something like [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb).

When you find that you write the same code repeatedly, you should factor out the common code into a helper function(/class/etc.); something to be called like this:

```objc
update_table_record(database, @"tableA",
                    @{ @"att0" : input0 },   // record ID
                    @{ @"attA1" : input1,    // new values
                       @"attA2" : input2 });
```

If your table records correspond to objects in your program, you might consider using an ORM, such as [chibi-ORM](http://code.google.com/p/chibiorm/) or [sqlitepersistentobjects](http://code.google.com/p/sqlitepersistentobjects/).